# Crear procedimiento almacenado PL/SQL usando cursores

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

Tengo una tabla con los nombres de unas rutas, pero mi problema es que los tramos de las rutas mezclan unidades en metros y en kilometros. Como se ve en la imagen, una misma ruta tiene los tramos en metros y otras en kilometros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que crear un procedimiento almacenado con el total de KM de cada ruta, es decir, me tiene que convertir los tramos de metros a kilometros y sumarlos para cada ruta (hay cuatro rutas).

¿Como puedo hacer el cambio de unidades y que me lo sume todo? Lo que he conseguido hasta el momento es esto:

```
    DECLARE
    CALCKM NUMBER(4);
    
    CURSOR C_TSEGMENT IS
       SELECT ROUTE, UNIT, SUM (DISTANCE)
       FROM TSEGMENT
       GROUP BY ROUTE, UNIT;
    BEGIN
    FOR R_TSEGMENT IN C_TSEGMENT LOOP   
      IF (UNIT = m) THEN (m/1000);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    END PS_TOTAL_DISTANCE;
```

Necesitaría poder ejecutarlo con un código como este:

```
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
    calckm();
    END;
```

Comment: Ese bloque PLSQL te funciona? Qué problema tiene? Y sobre el SP, qué problema tienes creándolo?

Answer (score 0):

Con esta consulta obtiene los resultados por Ruta:

```
select route,
       sum(case
             when unit='m' then
                distance/1000
             Else
                distance
           End) as sum_distanca
from TSEGMENT
group by ROUTE;
```